# Ajax post not working on datatables rendered button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I'm trying hard to get it done with JS as i'm pretty new to javascript.
I have datatable render `<a>` on one of the columns, which `on.click` opens bootstrap modal and send the values defined in it `<a data-name="' +row.name+ '".....>` etc to the input boxes in the modal.
Now there is `Save` button on the modal which should post the values of all these input boxes with ajax, but for some reason (which I might be missing) clicking on this button does nothing.
Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sohal/gfuuazxL/24/).

Answer (score 0):

This is because your submit button is out of `<form>` scope.
Try to submit the form on click event or move the button inside `<form>` scope.

Answer (score 0):

try this :-   clicking on this  passes values

```
 $("#submitBtn").on('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $.ajax({
         url: '/echo/html/',
         data: {
             html: "success"
         },
         type: "POST",
         data: $("#editUserForm").serialize(),
         contentType: false,
         cache: false,
         processData: false,
         success: function(data) {
             if (data === 'success') {
                 alert('Passed');
             } else {
                 alert('failed');
             }
         },
         error: function() {}
     });
 });
```

online : https://jsfiddle.net/gfuuazxL/27/